# What is the Difference between com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler and com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler

Tags: gwt, gwt-compiler

When i go through the `com.google.gwt.dev` package i found that there are two compilers available in `com.google.gwt.dev`.

My need is to compile a GWT project programatically from  my Java Application. Which one is suited?

Comment: Since you are just starting off with GWT, move to the latest edition of GWT i.e 2.5.1.  The older legacy compiler is removed. Latest GWT - https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Both the classes are the main executable entry point 
 for the GWT Java to JavaScript compiler.
```

But `com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler`  is **deprecated**

Use   `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`  (latest compiler from 2.5)

Here you can find the both classes `api`:

[GWTCompiler](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.0.4/gwt-dev-2.0.4-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/GWTCompiler.html)    // *here you can find that its deprecated*

[Compiler](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.0.4/gwt-dev-2.0.4-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/Compiler.html)

Comment: Broken links to javana

Answer (score 4):

`GWTCompiler` is the old entry point. The class has been deprecated for years, and has [finally been removed](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11411) starting with GWT 2.5.1-rc1.

Comment: Cheers 2.5.1 is out since two days - https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip