# GWT 2.7 with Netbeans not compiling

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I am learning GWT. And trying to create a HelloWorld in GWT using NetBeans. So I have created a new Web project and added GWT as *Frameworks* for the project. I am using *GlassFish 4.1* and *GWT SDK 2.7*. But when I try ro run the project, I am getting the below error,

***`Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler`***

When I change the GWT version to 2.7 from the project's properties. It is working fine. Also gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339600/what-is-the-difference-between-com-google-gwt-dev-compiler-and-com-google-gwt-de). Hence, it seems like te class *GWTCompiler* supposedly not to be used. How can I tell my project to use the compiler *`com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`*

Answer (score 5):

Just ran over the same problem. Fix it by doing the following.

Open build-gwt.xml

And look for the line

```
      <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-15" />
```

Remove it. Done :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is gwt-dev.jar in the classpath?  Apparently GWT 2.6.0 only needs gwt-user.jar, but GWT 2.7.0 needs both files in the classpath.